# In Ruby 1.9.3, check if the user input is a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, directory, ruby-1.9.3

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts  "Please enter the path-name of the directory:"
p = STDIN.gets  
isdir = File.directory?(p)  
puts "#{isdir} #{p}"
```

it always return me a false! even though I know the user input is a directory. I think (p) is not working as a parameter. So i think its saying that p is not a directory not the user input for example "/usr/bin/". any help?

Comment: maybe the variable `p` is not strictly equal to, let's say, `/etc/` but `/etc/\n`. Try to output the user's input (`puts p.inspect`) and eventually `strip` the user's input before using it --- I just tried it and it is actually the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using p = STDIN.gets '\n' was getting appended. Instead you can use gets.chomp. Also you need to use **File.expand_path**. Check the example below.

```
# My irb
1.9.3-p545 :002 >   p = gets.chomp
~/.ssh
=> "~/.ssh" 
1.9.3-p545 :003 > File.directory?(p) 
=> false 
1.9.3-p545 :004 > File.exists? File.expand_path(p)
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

The `p` value is not strictly equal to what you expect it to be. It contains `\n` at the end:

```
# in my irb:
1.9.3p392 :010 > p = STDIN.gets  
/home/
 => "/home/\n" 
1.9.3p392 :011 > isdir = File.directory?(p)  
 => false 
1.9.3p392 :012 > isdir = File.directory?(p.strip)  
 => true
```

---

The `strip` method:

> Strips entire range of Unicode whitespace from the right and left of the string.

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars/strip